# How to get value from dropdown list and insert it to MySQL table in deferent arrangement?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, combobox

I'm trying to retrieve data from MySQL table forma_table populate it in the html dropdown lists and then select and insert it in different arrangement to another table.
The problem is that the values in the dropdown options consist of sum of three strings: FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, EMAIL which I would like to save separately, means:
a) one field: FIRSTNAME + LASTNAME
b) second field: EMAIL

Currently I enter the value of "EK111" instead of EMAIL as I don't know how to make it happen.

Can anybody advice me how to do it.

Thanks.

```
<form name="Envelope" method="post" action="<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="ENVELOPE">
            <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="envelope">
            <input type="hidden" name="EmailKandydata" value="EK111" id="EMAILKANDYDATA">
            <label for="ENVELOPEKANDYDAT" id="Label1">Dane Kandydata</label>
            <input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Wybierz">
            <select name="Envelope Kandydat" size="1" id="ENVELOPEKANDYDAT">
<?php
   $mysql_server = 'serwer';
   $mysql_table = 'envelope_tab';
   $mysql_database = 'baza';
   $mysql_username = 'admin';
   $mysql_password = 'password';
   $link = mysqli_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password) or die('Failed to connect to database server!<br>'.mysqli_error($db));
   mysqli_select_db($link, $mysql_database);
   $res=mysqli_query($link, "select * from forma_table order by LASTNAME asc");
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
?> 
<option value="<?php echo $row[FIRSTNAME]; echo " "; echo $row[LASTNAME]; echo " "; echo $row[EMAIL]; ?>"><?php echo $row[FIRSTNAME]; echo " "; echo $row[LASTNAME]; echo " | "; echo $row[EMAIL]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
            </select>
</form>
```

Comment: You're going to get warnings. The columns should be quoted when pulling the data back out. `$row['LASTNAME']`, `$row['EMAIL'];`

Comment: Use the id of the `forma_table` in the `options value attribute` when you come to do stuff with whatever is selected, just go select that row again from the database and you have ALL the columns you want to do anything you want with

Comment: PS: You can echo multiple things and concatenate using the `.` like `echo 'Hello' . $fname . ' ' . $lname;` its a lot easier to read than all those echos

Comment: What isn't working the way you'd like it to? What results are you getting now as opposed to the desired results? Are you checking for errors at all, via php and mysql? I don't see any of that.

Comment: I don't follow the "EK111" comment, could you elaborate the two table structures you are dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

**Ideally**
Rather than reinsert all the information you should use a foreign key and reference the main record.

```
Table A             Table B 
-                   id
id        --->       contact_id_fk
```

**But you could do this:**

Make the value the id:

```
<option value="id">First Name <email>
```

Once the form is submitted, used the passed $id to fetch the remaining feilds.

```
$result = get_results (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE id = $id);
$first = $results['first_name']
```

Then insert into your new table:

```
Insert INTO ANOTHER TABLE VALUES($first, $last, $email)
```